# Ruby git gem: Git.ls_remote with ssh url gives undefined method `split' error on Bitrise

Tags: ruby, git, ssh, bitrise

Getting an error with the Ruby Git gem's Git.ls_remote command on Bitrise.

```
Git.ls_remote('git@github.com:company/repo_name.git')
```

is giving the error:

undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
(ref, type, name) = info.split('/', 3)

What I have realised is two things:

[1] the error actually seems to occur when processing the output from Git.ls_remote, so it doesn't actually seem to be an issue with the ssh url (which is what I thought originally).

[2] This issue is only occurring when running this on Bitrise. Once I set-up all the ssh stuff locally, and run the same ls_remote code locally, I don't get this issue.

I'm thinking then that maybe there's an issue on Bitrise with running Ruby's Git.ls_remote.

Comment: Can it take `ssh://git@github.com/company/repo_name.git` instead?

Comment: Jim, that was a good idea. Unfortunately, it's not fixed the issue. What I have realised though is two things: [1] the error actually seems to occur when processing the output from Git.ls_remote, so i doesn't actually seem to be an issue with the ssh url. [2] This issue is only occurring when running this on Bitrise. Once I set-up all the ssh stuff locally, and run the same ls_remote code locally, I don't get this issue. Will update the question.